# Transpose log rows to multiple colums in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

My company store Log_Info in one table, with factory id, department id, log date, log hour, log minute with counter value. Please help me how to tranpose [Log hour + Log min] to columns as we can see in this case using PL/SQL in Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.

Thank you very much.

[image: Our Log_Info]

Comment: [Please don't post images when you don't have to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Show your raw data, expected results and your current best attempt as formatted text, and explain what problem you are having. Does this really need to involve PL/SQL?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can use C# to generate results, but with amount of large data, in one or two years, using foreach to check and then filling one by one is very slow. But select direct in SQL is very fast, so I hope PL/SQL is  good choice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tell you to use PIVOT, which is an extremely easy way of doing this kind of thing natively, but unfortunately I believe that was introduced in 11g. As far as I know, you have two options; if you want to stay in native SQL, you must use case statements that are hardcoded. Otherwise, this solution may be useful to you..

```
declare v_str varchar2(2000);
begin
v_str:='select factoryid,deptid,logdate';
for i in (select distinct 'H'||loghour||'_'||logmin a from test_table order by a) loop
    v_str:=v_str||',max(case ''H''||loghour||''_''||logmin when '''||i.a||''' then counter end) as "'||i.a||'"';
end loop;
    v_str:=v_str||' from test_table group by factoryid,deptid,logdate order by factoryid';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_str);
end;
```

This will give you a dynamic query that you can then execute in a loop or into a result set, whatever you choose (instead of the PUT_LINE I have here). The result of this block based on the current data you provided is:

```
    select factoryid,deptid,logdate,
max(case 'H'||loghour||'_'||logmin when 'H0_0' then counter end) as "H0_0",
max(case 'H'||loghour||'_'||logmin when 'H0_30' then counter end) as "H0_30",
max(case 'H'||loghour||'_'||logmin when 'H1_0' then counter end) as "H1_0",
max(case 'H'||loghour||'_'||logmin when 'H1_30' then counter end) as "H1_30",
max(case 'H'||loghour||'_'||logmin when 'H2_0' then counter end) as "H2_0" 
from test_table 
group by factoryid,deptid,logdate order by factoryid
```

which will give you exactly what you're looking for.

EDIT: As a note, the MAX is included to eliminate everything in the case statement from being in the group by. This is assuming there will be only one counter value per time per factory id/deptid/logdate.

If you'd like to go the native route and have a defined list of loghour and logmin (not 100% sure, but it seems like you would be going from H0_0 to H23_30), you can use the query the PL/SQL block spit out above, and continue creating case statements until all loghours and logmins are accounted for. If this is the case and loghour/min have a defined span, you should do this as there are performance benefits, such as cursor caching, to using native SQL over dynamic SQL.